Graph theory approach to find the best sequence of implications to prove the equivalence of N statements
Suppose we have N statements that are known to be equivalent and suppose we know how difficult it is to prove every implication. which is the easiest way to prove that they are equivalent?
This problem can be stated in terms of graph theory in the following way:
We have a complete directed graph G with N nodes and for every edge (n1,n2) there is a weight Wn1n2 in (0,+inf). we would like to find a path such that in the subgraph G* (the subgraph created by the path) there is always a path from one node to another, minimizing at the same time the sum of Wn1n2 with (n1,n2) in G*.
I found some algorithms but they are extremely inefficient.
Thank you.

See this post and references therein:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536067/minimum-cost-strongly-connected-digraph
Looks like the problem is NP-hard, so yes the algorithms won’t be efficient

Sounds like it is exactly the same as the Traveling Salesman Problem, a well know NP-hard problem.
